# How to run a sleepy process in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, process

I need to change the state of  group of processes from sleep (S) to run (R), is there any command to perform this quickly  and note that I have their PIDs.

[image]

Comment: HHow did you pause them? Using kill? (Stop)

Comment: no , I used one virtual machine as master and issued a command that needs to be executed in parallel with the help of other 15 slaves and each task of the program needs 8 threads .... 
when I opened the GUI for them I found the 8 process utilize 0% of CPU and with the state "sleep"

Comment: @JacobVlijm ,, is there away to specify state "Run" for all of them from the master machine when I issues the execution command for my program?

Comment: No clue if it works, but could you try `kill -cont 22541`? (where 22541 is the pid of the proc)

Comment: I tried this way ... but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, so I'll just post an answer.

You may need to apply the kill "cont" command to all of the child processes, like this...

```
ps -eL | grep python | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 kill -s cont
```

If this doesn't help you, you may want to investigate why the processes are falling in to wait states to begin with.  A strategically placed 'echo -n' might shed some light.  For example, are they expecting input from a user or another process?

Good luck.

Comment: not help. I used this command:: ./cado-nfs.py "larg number" slaves.hostnames="range of ip addresses (15 machine)" --slaves 15 --client-threads 8 --server-threads 8

Comment: Its a problem regarding CADO-NFS to make factorization using multiple machines